# Making cursor position animation more in-your-face

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse-cursor

I can set this:
*Mouse Properties* -> *Pointer Options* -> *Visibility* -> *Show location of pointer when I press the CTRL key* but on six 24" screens the little circle this produces is often not large enough for me to see.

Does anyone know of any program (or otherwise) that can either increase the size of the animation or have some other way of at least identifying which monitor the cursor is on?

Comment: How are the screens arranged, and how far away are you from them? If the large animated circles aren't visible enough for you to find the cursor, then I'd imagine you'd have a pretty hard time reading most UI text with that display arrangement as well. If you lower your display resolution, then the cursor, the locate cursor animation, and UI text will all be larger, and you probably won't miss the resolution change if you're so far away the current cursor location animation is too small to see.

Comment: @Lèse there is no issue with the current resolution or readabiliy.  The screens are in a 3x2 arrangement, so when you're looking at screen 3,1 then screens 1,1 and 1,2 are at peripheral vision making noticing the animation difficult.  Also, if the cursor is at an extreme corner of a screen, you only see 1/4 of the animated circle, which is only about 1-2 inches - comparatively this is not "large" considering the full 6x24" viewing surface...

Answer (score 0):

Switch on pointer trails

Move the cursor a bit, it will be very easy to find then